# Grouping Tuples that Share Elements into Separate Lists

Tags: python, sorting, tuples, grouping

Given this set of data

```
[ (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(7,8),(8,9),(8,11),(12,19) ]
```

I am trying to get to this result

```
 [ [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] , [(7,8),(8,9),(8,11)] , [(12,19)] ]
```

The order of the results does not matter.

What I am trying to do is group the elements who are 'linked' into separate lists.

This is what I have so far but I am getting a bit stuck

```
for a,b in links:
    result=[(a,b)]
    tmplinks.remove((a,b))
    for c,d in tmplinks:
        if a==c or a==d or b==c or b==d:
            result.append((c,d))
```

The result should be able to work on strings because I am working with strings representing IP addressses.

```
Starting Data
[ ('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'),('2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3'),('4.4.4.4','6.6.6.6'),('6.6.6.6','11.11.11.11') ]

Desired Output
[ [ ('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'),('2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3') ] , [ ('4.4.4.4','6.6.6.6'),('6.6.6.6','11.11.11.11') ] ]


1.1.1.1
|
2.2.2.2
|
3.3.3.3


4.4.4.4
|
6.6.6.6
|
11.11.11.11
```

Comment: @Kasra If you use that program you can get what the OP wants. Anyway retracted my Close vote

Comment: @AnselGaddy Do you prefer any alternative outputs?

Comment: @Bhargav Rao Each tuple represents a link for creating graphs, the items in the tuples are the nodes. The end result should be separate lists for each grouping of connected nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some variations of your requirements (eg. an item could be inserted in any matching group or only if it matches with the last element of the last group) and vice versa, but I oriented myself on your example and it came to this:

```
def group(items):
  iterator = iter(items)
  group = [next(iterator)]
  result =[group]
  for item in iterator:
    (a, b), (c, d) = item, group[-1]
    if a in (c, d) or b in (c, d):
      group.append(item)
    else:
      group = [item]
      result.append(group)
  return result

print(group([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(7,8),(8,9),(2,1),(2,3),(1,4)]))
```

Outputs: `[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(7, 8), (8, 9)], [(2, 1), (2, 3)], [(1, 4)]]` [Ideone](http://ideone.com/L9obap)

Comment: Upon further inspection some of the results are not clustered together when they should be.

At most the results from this are related by one order of distance and they can be long chains of linked items. I think possibly I need to run another loop in this.

Comment: I didn't see your edit about IP addresses when I posted my solution. Could you please show me input data for which it does not work they way you expect it?

Comment: @ Niklas R - thanks for your continued help with this
[pastebin of obfuscated IP addresses](http://pastebin.com/YD7vhDTu)  there are seperate 'clusters' in the results which share IP addresses and these I am wanting to group together

Comment: These are not valid IP addresses but I had to obfuscate the IPs because they are production routers.

If you look down the pastebin you can see I wrote a little method to return the 'groups' that share a common IP, therefore they should be merged.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't preserve the ordering on the edges, but it finds the clusters very easily:

```
nums = [ (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(7,8),(8,9),(8,11),(12,19) ]
ips = [ ('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'),('2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3'),('4.4.4.4','6.6.6.6'),('6.6.6.6','11.11.11.11') ]

import networkx as nx


for testdata in (nums, ips):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_edges_from(testdata)
    sub_graphs = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)

    # you can now loop through all nodes in each sub graph
    for s in sub_graphs:
     print(s.edges())
```

> ```
> [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
> [(8, 9), (8, 11), (8, 7)]
> [(19, 12)]
>
> [('11.11.11.11', '6.6.6.6'), ('4.4.4.4', '6.6.6.6')]
> [('3.3.3.3', '2.2.2.2'), ('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2')]
> ```

Comment: and if you're working on actual networks, the chances that networkx will be otherwise useful seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
input1 = [ (1,2),(2,3),(7,8),(3,4),(8,9),(8,11), (12,19)]
temp_input = input1[:]

result_list = []
for a,b in input1:
    if (a,b) in temp_input :
        result=[(a,b)]
        temp_input.remove( (a,b) )
        result_list.append( result )
    for c,d in temp_input :
        if a==c or a==d or b==c or b==d:
            result.append( (c,d) )
            temp_input.remove( (c,d) )
print result_list
```

Comment: Does not produce the expected output.
Output: [[(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(3, 4)], [(8, 11), (7, 8)]]
Expected: [ [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] , [(7,8),(8,9),(8,11)] , [(12,19)] ]

Comment: I receive the following result, did you miss somethings?
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(7, 8), (8, 9), (8, 11)], [(12, 19)]]

Comment: Sorry I revisited this and it works as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this k-mean clustering algorithm. you can see this link for [K-mean](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans) implementation in python.

```
N.B:need must be told how many group you need?
```

Also you can see for better understand [A pure python implementation of K-Means clustering](https://gist.github.com/iandanforth/5862470).

I think it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following:

```
[lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
```

---

```
>>> lst = [ (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(7,8),(8,9),(8,11),(12,19) ]
>>> [lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(7, 8), (8, 9), (8, 11)], [(12, 19)]]
>>>
```

Comment: This is not a answer to this question at all!

Comment: Seems to group elements together in lists of 3 items but does not produce the intended effect.

Comment: @Kasra  the output is exactly what OP wants....why do you think this does not answer the question?

Comment: @vks *What I am trying to do is group the elements who are 'linked' into separate lists*